# How to provide a counter field for every user in django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to provide a counter field in my `Group1` model i.e. whenever a user create a new group1 object it will save the counter as it is...

**For example:**

If a user create a new group1 object it will save the counter field value as 1, then 2 for another new group1 object and so on.
And I want to do this for every user i.e. for every user the counter field value should start from 1.

This is my `Group1` model:

```
class Group1(models.Model):
   counter = models.IntegerField()
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
   group_Name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

Do anyone have any idea about how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the groups that the user has already created and add one to it.

```
def group_create_view(request):
    user = request.user
    # Get the count for groups that this user has made and add one
    counter = Group1.objects.filter(user=user).count() + 1
    new_group = Group1.objects.create(user=user, counter=counter, group_name='some_name')
```

Comment: Should I do it in my views?

Comment: You can do it any where.